# Polite/professional auto-acknowledgment email for support inquries

Tags: grammar, expressions, politeness

I am trying to create an auto acknowledgment email for support requests we receive. I want it to look polite and professional, but I find it a bit difficult to word properly since I am not a native speaker. How does my email look?

> Subject: Your message is received
>
> Thank you very much for your message! `[optional(a): We know your time is valuable and we would like to acknowledge that we have received your request.]`
>
> We work hard on answering every support message as quickly as possible
>   and usually respond within a few hours or less. Occasionally, `[optional(b): 
>   due to the high number of inquiries we receive,]` we might not be able get back
>   to you right away. While you are waiting, another great source for
>   answers is our FAQ section: http://www.example.com/support
>
> Thank you for your patience.
>
> `[optional(c): Sincerely,]`
>
> Support Team

Comment: This is generally a very well-written boilerplate message. Unfortunately, questions that amount to requests for opinions such as the one I just gave or for proofreading help are off-topic for this site. As a result, this question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a native speaker of American English. Everything looks grammatically correct to me, and it reads clearly and professionally.

As a fellow programmer, I feel like users appreciate seeing a more personable response, even if it is just auto-generated, especially if it's in response to something that took them a bit of time to complete. It makes them feel important to your company. For that reason, I would add all of the optional sections you've suggested to the final email template.

Comment: @Parsusta I missed one grammar error in "optional a". There should be a comma between "valuable" and "and", since they are both complete sentences joined by a conjunction.